# How to change or set subitems of a listview from AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-asynctask

In my MainActivity I have a listview with two lines of text for each row. Only the first line is written when the app is started, the second line must be written based on the things processed by an AsyncTask class. When I try to do it, the first item of the listview gets all the values AsyncTask gives, because I don't understand how to update **only** the second line of the listview for **each** item, without rewriting the whole listview.
Every textView has its own id in the xml layout file. How can I do it in the onPostExecute()?
Here's the code:

In MainActivity onCreate():

```
    final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    final String[] values = new String[10];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        //do stuff to write the values[] elements

    }

    MySimpleArrayAdapter adapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(this, values);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

MySimpleArrayAdapter class:

```
public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
  private final Context context;
  private final String[] values;
  int position=0;

  public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_layout, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, parent, false);
    TextView firstLine = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    TextView secondLine = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.sublabel);

    firstLine.setText(values[position]);
    secondLine.setText(""); //I prefer to write an empty string for the secondLine

    return rowView;
  }
}
```

The AsyncTask:

```
private class Process extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //do stuff
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String message) {
        TextView secondLine = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sublabel);

        //This of course udpdates only the secondLine of the first item of listview
        secondLine.setText(processedValues);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to execute the `AsyncTask` for it to work..

Comment: Yeah, sorry I forgot to mention it. It executes in a method clicking a button, but that's not the point of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass the TextView as a parameter to the AsyncTask as follows

```
private class Process extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
private WeakReference<TextView> weakTextView;
public Process(TextView textView){
       weakTextView = new WeakReference<TextView>(textView);
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    //do stuff
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String message) {
    TextView tv = weakTextView.get();
   if(tv!=null){
       tv.setText(message);
 }
}
```

}

you call this in your `getView` as

```
Process p = new Process(yourTextView);
p.execute();
```

//method number two

```
private class Process extends AsyncTask<TextView, Void, String> {

private WeakReference<TextView> weakTextView;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(TextView... params) {
    if(params == null||params.length=0){
         return null;
    }
    TextView tv = (TextView)params[0];
    weakTextView = new WeakReference<TextView>(tv);

    //do stuff
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String message) {
    TextView tv = weakTextView.get();
   if(tv!=null){
       tv.setText(message);
 }
}
```

}

you call this in your `getView` as

```
Process p = new Process();
p.execute(yourTextView);
```

//method 3

just update the underline data object of this list adapter
and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`
which will call `getView` again
this method, in most cases, is preferable to the other 2 above, unless you are displaying images from the internet

Comment: What do you mean with "update the underline data object" ? I guess I'm getting lost in a glass of water...

Comment: i guess the question is, why do you need an async task to update the contents of the given textview ?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I've been busy. I need AsyncTask to do other things and at the end it updates the lines of listview. ANyway I solved my problem using your method 3 after a few tries. The key was adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() indeed so thank you very much!